# Несогласованное определение или сказуемое?

Tags: сказуемое

У Лопатина в параграфе о бессоюзном сложном предложении о случаях постановки тире перед второй частью предложения приведен пример: Черемуха была крупная, в длинных и чистых, без листа, тяжелых гроздьях — только успевай подставляй под них руки (Расп.).

Здесь *в длинных и чистых, без листа, тяжелых гроздьях* - это несогласованное определение или входит в состав сказуемого?

Если это несогласованное определение, то нужно его слева обособить запятой?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Черемуха была крупная, в длинных и чистых, без листа, тяжелых гроздьях - однородные сказуемые, после них запятая не нужна.